# My Documents Folder - Path different to folder name

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, my-documents

In Windows 7 I had moved `My Documents` to My D:\ drive and called it "Docs". I have since added other folders (for my wife and kids) so have renamed it with my name "Ciaran"

In both Windows 7 and Windows 10, the display folder name was "Ciaran" but the path is `D:\Docs` when I look in the address bar of Windows Explorer.

How do I change the folder path to Ciaran i.e. `D:\Ciaran`?

<strike>Interestingly if I rename it to Ciaran1 the path becomes `D:\Ciaran1` but reverts to `D:\Docs` if I rename it back to Docs.</strike>
This is incorrect - even when renaming the folder the path remains `D:\Docs` but the desktop.ini for the folder changes the `LocalizedResourceName` to `Ciaran1`

Presumably it is some registry setting but not sure where to look and it could take a while to find it.

`PowerShell:`

```
PS D:\> ls

    Directory: D:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       05/07/2019     17:18                Folder1
d-r---       14/01/2020     23:42                Docs
d-----       13/12/2019     23:18                Folder2
d-----       08/10/2019     08:53                Folder3
da----       25/10/2019     16:33                Folder4
```

`D:\ desktop.ini`

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

`desktop.ini` for `D:\Docs` aka `D:\Ciaran`

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=Ciaran
IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll,4
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

Comment: Please be aware that Windows 10v1809 had a terrible bug where redirected folders were deleted on upgrade.  While Microsoft is unlikely to repeat that specific blunder, make doubly sure that you have a regular backup plan of important files.  https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/10/09/microsoft-lost-files-issue-windows-10.aspx

Comment: @ChristopherHostage The issue you speak of has zero to do with the OP's question and does not apply.  The issue in that article is specific to the _first_ public build version of the **v1809 update _only_** and it only affected a minute amount of users who took the v1809 update when it was first offered, which Microsoft pulled from the update servers within a short time after it became available _(v1809 was delayed for weeks afterwards)_ and the v1809 build version that resulted with this bug is no longer publicly available _(this is not what the OP is experiencing)_.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support hot-swapping user data directories in this way.

To do so:

- Right-click on directory (`D:\Docs`) > Properties > Location Tab > New path (`D:\Ciaran`) > OK

  - If `D:\Docs` properties does not have a Location tab, then you'll need to perform the above procedure on the `%UserProfile%\Documents` directory.

Answer (score -1):

Things can get confusing because the user folders that appear under **This PC** can have display names different than their filesystem names. The most relible way to determine true filesytem names is **PowerShell** or a **Command Prompt**.

The display name is supplied by the contents of the **desktop.ini** file. Normally, it references language-specific folder names:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

But remaming can yield:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=Renamed Folder
...
```

desktop.ini files normally have both Hidden & Sytem attributes set, so **Explorer** view settings must be set to both **Show Hidden Files...** and not **Hide Protected OS Files**.

If you need more help untangling, post a screenshot of D:\ from both **PowerShell** & **Explorer**.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the screenshots. However the obvious solution is starig us in the face - create a new folder called Ciaran and copy the files across - worked a treat. But it would still be interesting as to what the underlying solution is.

Comment: Yes, renaming only affects the display name. But if you use **Move** from the **Location** tab, you can create a file folder with the desired name and move the folder to that location.

Comment: This is overcomplicating an extraordinarily simple issue... simply navigate to the Documents folder Windows is currently set to use, right-click on it > Properties > Location tab.

Comment: `JW0914`: That's what I told him to do once I had verified the circumstances. The OP was attempting a rename & not getting desired results. I explained the probable cause & requested more info. If you looked at the question in its original form, you would understand my answer.

Comment: @KeithMiller The `desktop.ini` has no purpose/bearing in this context.  User data directories are hardcoded into the registry, which is one reason why the correct way of performing a target change should be used _(directories' Properties > Location tab)_.  All of my user data directories are stored on a separate partition, and not a single one has anything referencing this change in the `desktop.ini`, as the file has no bearing in this context.  You're talking about having the directory appear with a different name **_without_** a target change _in your answer_, which is not the OP's issue.

Comment: You are mistaken. Desktop.ini was responsible for the name change the OP inquired about.

Comment: @KeithMiller That's factually inaccurate. To verify, please test it yourself: Right-click on a user data directory in `%UserProfile%` > Properties > Location Tab > move to a custom path > open directory's `desktop.ini`.  If that doesn't convince, delete `desktop.ini` once the directory has been moved, refresh Explorer [`F5`], and if what you say is correct, directory should default back to its non-customized target state _(which will not occur, as the `desktop.ini` has no bearing at all on customized targets for user data directories)_. OP has an issue with the path, **not** the directory name

Comment: _But the situation you describe was not the OP's!_ The OP couldn't understand why, after an attempted rename, the display name would change but not the source folder name. It's difficult to explain that _without_ mentoning the desktop.ini file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103427/discussion-between-jw0914-and-keith-miller).

Comment: @KeithMiller Please refer to the 3rd and 4th sentences in the OP's question, which should thoroughly clear this up: _"In both Windows 7 and Windows 10, the display folder name was `Ciaran` but the **path is `D:\Docs`** when I look in the address bar of Windows Explorer.

How do I change **the folder path** to `Ciaran` i.e. `D:\Ciaran`?_

Comment: No. I'm low vision & the chat page doesn't zoom well. I understand this better than you. I'm a former MS MVP Shell/User. You need to examine the behavior of the **Rename** command when the folder being renamed has a _LocalizedResourceName_ supplied by a desktop.ini file.

Comment: @KeithMiller Best of luck =]

Answer (score -1):

The solution all be it a slight workaround was to create a new folder called Ciaran and copy the files across.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the built-in option to do this via the document folder properties' location tab?  I'm perplexed why you appear to be trying to find a "workaround", rather than using the feature that is there to do what you want to do.

Comment: Because it doesn't work...

Comment: What doesn't work?  If the folder properties you're in don't have a Location tab, it's not the user documents directory (Navigate to the following in Explorer `%UserProfile%\Documents`).  If the directory you're trying to move has a Location tab, and following the directions in my answer doesn't work, then you have a corrupted Windows install: you can try to repair via: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot & re-run if corruption found > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot. If that doesn't resolve, perform a Repair Install of Windows.